# Can you use user entered data from a while loop and put it into a loop

Tags: arrays, perl, while-loop

I would like to take this user data entered and put it into an array and I cant seem to figure out how to do it though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use diagnostics;

my ($number,$smallest,$largest);
print "\nPlease enter a number or -1 to end,Press enter after every number  entered\n";
chomp ($number =<>);
$smallest = $number;

$largest=$number; 
while($number !=0) 
{
$smallest = $number if $number < $smallest;
$largest  = $number if $number > $largest;
chomp ($number=<>);
}
print "\n$smallest:$largest\n";
```

Comment: You should probably start by creating the array... `my @foo;` and then adding to it: `push(@foo, $number);`

Comment: Your print is not correct: `-1` does not end your loop, but `0` does.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to collect data in a loop would be something like this:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    last if $_ < 0;        # -1 ends the loop
    push @array, $_;       # save number

    if ($_ < $smallest) {
        $smallest = $_;
    }
    elsif ($_ > $largest) {
        $largest = $_;
    }
}
```

Using a `while (<>)` is the idiomatic way, so that is why I am using it here.

You could also put it together, and use the array to find the smallest and largest number:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    last if $_ < 0;
    push @array, $_;
}

@array = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;
print "\n$array[0]:$array[-1]\n";
```

Here you simply sort the array and then use the first and last element.